# How to insert multiple insert sql statement

Tags: sql, oracle

There is a table Person(id, name). I am inserting more than 1000 records into person table. Both id and name should be unique. I wrote something like this

```
INSERT ALL 
       INTO PERSON (1, 'MAYUR')
       INTO PERSON (2, 'SALUNKE') 
       .....(1000 records)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

I am getting unique constraint for name in this query. How do I know which record in particular is failing. All I see in logs is this

> Error starting at line : 3 in command - ORA-00001: unique constraint
>   (UN_PERSON_NAME) violated.

This does not tell the exact record which is duplicate.

Comment: Quite confuse with insert all then select *, if u really want to know which line have issue, better split these into separate line.

Comment: First, insert into temp table(temp_person) with no unique constraints, then group by name to see which name is duplicated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing `values` keyword. Try this!

```
INSERT ALL 
       INTO PERSON values(1, 'MAYUR')
       INTO PERSON values(2, 'SALUNKE') 
       .....(1000 records)
SELECT * FROM DUAL;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
INSERT INTO table2 (column1, column2, column3, ...)
SELECT column1, column2, column3, ...
FROM table1
```

Comment: While this answer may be useful, It is advised to give proper explaination about what the problem is and how it you have solved

Comment: if you want to insert data from one table to another table just use this query to insert data.but you have same length of column in select and insert statement

Answer (score -1):

Unfortunately, Oracle doesn't support multiple inserts using a single `VALUES()` statement.  I usually approach this as:

```
INSERT PERSON (id, name)
    SELECT 1, 'MAYUR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
    SELECT 2, 'SALUNKE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
       .....;
```

One advantage of this approach is you can use a subquery and assign the id:

```
INSERT PERSON (id, name)
    SELECT rownum, x.name
    FROM (SELECT 'MAYUR' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
          SELECT 'SALUNKE' FROM DUAL UNION ALL 
          .....
         ) x
```